# What is an efficient way to insert and then select with tsql?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

For a given Id, I want to select a record from a DB table.
If the record doesn't exist I want to insert it with some default values and return the record.

What is the best way to do so?
My problem is to insert and then select. It seems inefficient.

Comment: Which database are you using, say something like [Output clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) might work for sql server

Comment: What percentage of the time do you expect the record to be there already?

Comment: It *seems* or you proved that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the record doesn't exist, and you have to create it, you don't have much choice in the matter.  The exception to this may be if the table in question does not have an identity column, or any computed columns and what you put in is basically all there is.  Then you could potentially insert it, then just return an object you initialised yourself from the default values you put it.

However, if you are using identity columns or anything else that the database insertion will provide for you (including triggers), then you can't do much else than select the data back after insertion.

Answer (score 2):

I would attempt the insert, with a "WHERE NOT EXISTS" condition, and then select the row that we know definitely exists at that point*:

```
INSERT INTO <Table> (<Columns>)
SELECT <Column Values> WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM <Table> WHERE <Key Column Match Conditions>)

SELECT <Select Columns Needed> FROM <Table> WHERE <Key Column Match Conditions>
```

This has the benefit that it always returns a single result to whatever's calling it - some solutions (e.g. INSERT with OUTPUT and a SELECT, either way around) produce multiple result sets, which may not work well with whatever is consuming the output.

---

*Unless you're also in a race with potential deletes from the table - but you haven't mentioned this possibility yet, so we don't know what the desired output would be if a delete happens immediately after the insert.

Comment: +1, and I think the author should accept this answer and not mine.  I had totally forgotten about the INSERT..INTO...SELECT paradigm.